# How does git-diff generate hunk descriptions?

Tags: python, git, diff

(git version 1.6.5.7)

When I run `git diff` the output has a nice scope hint after the line numbers for my Python scripts, e.g.:

```
diff --git a/file.py b/file.py
index 024f5bb..c3b5c56 100644
--- a/file.py
+++ b/file.py
@@ -14,6 +14,8 @@ TITF: Test Infrastructure Tags Format
...
@@ -1507,13 +1533,16 @@ class Tags( object ):
...
```

Note that the line numbers are followed by `TITF: Test Infrastructure Tags Format` and `class Tags( object ):`. The first patch applies to module scope and the description `TITF: Test Infrastructure Tags Format` is the module's description. The second patch applies to a method of the `Tags` class.

1. How does git generate these descriptions?
2. How can I tweak them to show the method name that the patch applies to?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Git uses a regular expression to find a suitable line for the hunk headers. Python's is built-in, but you should be able to define your own expression in your ~/.gitconfig:

```
[diff "python"]
        xfuncname = "<regex goes here>"
```

More about this [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html).

**Edit**: The built-in python regex seems to be defined in [userdiff.c](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=blob;f=userdiff.c;hb=HEAD) (line 53), although my regex-fu is not good enough to actually understand exactly what it does...

```
PATTERNS("python", "^[ \t]*((class|def)[ \t].*)$",
         /* -- */
         "[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*"
         "|[-+0-9.e]+[jJlL]?|0[xX]?[0-9a-fA-F]+[lL]?"
         "|[-+*/<>%&^|=!]=|//=?|<<=?|>>=?|\\*\\*=?"
         "|[^[:space:]|[\x80-\xff]+"),
         /* -- */
```

Comment: Interestingly "*.py diff=python" changes the behavior to be as I'd like even without defining a custom [diff "python"], but "*.py +diff" (apparently my default) behaves as shown in my question.

Comment: "*.py diff=python" tells git to use the options defined under [diff "python"] (or the predefined default), "*.py +diff" just enables a textual diff. This switch is usually used for disabling diffs for files that are not always detected as binary, e.g. "*.ps -diff" will treat PostScript files as binary and thus doesn't show a diff.

Comment: although for binary files it may be advisable to set "*.ps binary" which is an alias for "-crlf -diff", i.e. it disables CRLF<->LF processing for the file too.

Comment: The GNU diff has similar `-p` / `--show-c-function` option, which was inspiration for its git-diff equivalent / generalization.

Comment: For those who wonder what "*.py diff=python" is, I'd like to mention that this is a line in a .gitattributes file (if I'm not mistaken).

Answer (score 1):

With Git 2.25 (Q1 2020), the `userdiff` machinery has been taught that "`async def`" is another way to begin a "function" in Python.

See [commit 077a1fd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/077a1fda82b237c16eb10bd988650468683a94b5) (19 Nov 2019) by [Josh Holland (`anowlcalledjosh`)](https://github.com/anowlcalledjosh).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 9502b61](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9502b616f187c567b93db69cd9c6f0028019bd15), 05 Dec 2019)</sup>

> ### [`userdiff`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/077a1fda82b237c16eb10bd988650468683a94b5): support Python async functions
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Josh Holland</sup>
> <sup>Acked-by: Johannes Sixt</sup>
>
> Python's `async` functions (declared with "`async def`" rather than "`def`") were not being displayed in hunk headers.
> This commit teaches Git about the `async` function syntax, and adds tests for the Python `userdiff` regex.