# Is there a way to ask git diff to show the method name instead of the class name?

Tags: php, git, diff

This has been bugging me for a while and searching has yielded no hints.

**Issue:**

When I do a `git diff` on a PHP file containing a `Class`, each hunk description has the class name with no mention of the method name.

**For example:**

```
@@ -351,7 +351,7 @@ class Session
             $form->setError($field, $subpassValid['msg']);
       }

       // E-Mail address error checking
       $field = "email";  //Use field name for email
-       if(!isset($subemail) || strlen($subemail = trim($subemail)) == 0){
+       if(!$subemail || strlen($subemail = trim($subemail)) == 0){
          $form->setError($field, "* Email not entered");
@@ -373,7 +373,7 @@ class Session
...
```

**Question:**

Is there a way to tell `git` to show method names instead of/along side of the class name?

**Edit:**

*Additional Information:*

```
diff version: 2.8.1
git version: 1.7.6 (from the git-core PPA)
OS: Ubuntu 9.10
```

I originally had git version 1.7.0.4 from the stock Ubuntu repos, but updated it hoping that it was a bug. Unfortunately that didn't solve the issue.

<strike>**Edit2:**</strike>

After more testing, it appears that if the function declaration is indented at all (with either spaces or tabs) `git diff` doesn't pick up the function name. This appears to be a bug in `git`.

Comment: Some more info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783086/how-does-git-diff-generate-hunk-descriptions

Comment: Looks like we have a bug. [It should work exactly like you want it to.](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/userdiff.c#L92)

Comment: What is the exact filename you display the diff of?

Comment: @hakre The behavior I am referring to is uniform across the board. It happens when I call `git diff session.php` (from which the example is taken from) or `git diff master` or just `git diff --staged`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you find yourself having this issue, it might be due to the fact that `git` lets `diff` define the hunk header. If you want to force `git` to use its predefined ones for PHP place the following line in either `.gitattributes` in the root folder of your git repository or the `.git/info/attributes` file in your repository:

```
*.php diff=php
```

(Other languages are similarly supported.  A list of the built in patterns is available in the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_defining_a_custom_hunk_header).)

#### Setting this Globally

It should be possible to globally set this by doing the following in `git version >= 1.4`

1. Put line(s) in `~/.gitattributes`
2. Run `git config --global core.attributesfile "~/.gitattributes"`

Or if you want to  set this globally

1. Put line(s) into `/etc/gitattributes`

**Warning:** If you personally set this globally, your peers may get different results when running `git diff` since they won't checkout a copy of `.gitattributes` with the repository.

Answer (score 8):

I don't quite understand why it doesn't work [the way it should](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6d2f208c3dd39493f4d45ea67c55a1b7fe06626a).

As a temporary solution, add the following to `.gitattributes`:

```
*.php   diff=phpf
```

And these lines to `.git/config` or `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[diff "phpf"]
        xfuncname = "^[\t ]*(((public|protected|private|static)[\t ]+)*function.*)$"
```

For a permanent solution ask Git developers directly at [git@vger.kernel.org mailing list](http://dir.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git).

Comment: Doing the above removes that part completely. Using the above example,  `class Session` has now disappeared, replaced by nothing. I've added version numbers to the original question if that helps any.

Comment: I think the `\n` at the end breaks it; it is used somehow to separate regexes and you have only one here. Without that, it worked for me. (The other solution is more elegant though.)

Answer (score 1):

That diff would likely be better with Git 2.19 (Q3 2018), since the userdiff pattern for `.php` has been updated.

See [commit 1ab6316](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1ab631647e3addd247c5482e8a3d4c9df7978c62), [commit 9992fbd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9992fbd7a1fdcc8fbaf0973a18d0eca94e1b7638) (03 Jul 2018) by [Kana Natsuno (`kana`)](https://github.com/kana).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d3f0938](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d3f09389731e186a978f095228431b1bb293b6f6), 24 Jul 2018)</sup>

> ### userdiff: support new keywords in PHP hunk header
>
> Recent version of PHP supports **`interface`**, **`trait`**, **`abstract class`** and
> **`final class`**.
> This patch fixes the PHP hunk header regexp to support all of these keywords.

---

And it does improve with Git 2.30 (Q1 2021):

See [commit aff9282](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aff92827b54f4b7f9e339982a49bab4bdbd1fc55) (07 Oct 2020) by [Javier Spagnoletti (`phansys`)](https://github.com/phansys).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit a8a49eb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a8a49ebf61449f80d8c5ea2f9768f0ca590e51dd), 27 Oct 2020)</sup>

> ### [`userdiff`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aff92827b54f4b7f9e339982a49bab4bdbd1fc55): PHP: catch "abstract" and "final" functions
>
> <sup>Helped-by: Johannes Sixt</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Javier Spagnoletti</sup>

> PHP permits functions to be defined like
>
> ```
> final public function foo() { }
> abstract protected function bar() { }
> ```
>
> but our hunk header pattern does not recognize these decorations.
>
> **Add "`final`" and "`abstract`" to the list of function modifiers.**