# Is there something similar to diff --show-c-function in git-diff?

Tags: diff, git-diff

I've been working on a file in my git repository.  If I have a copy of the original git version of the file, I can run diff --show-c-function to get a comparison of the 2, files, where (in theory) it shows the whole of any function which has been changed.  This is really useful for working out what I did specifically to a file, in working out the comment I'd need.

However in git-diff, this option is missing.  Is there some way to make this work (or am I stuck having to get 2 copies of the file before I can commit, where the git-diff response is slightly complicated)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`git help diff` shows this option:

```
-W, --function-context
        Show whole surrounding functions of changes.
```

So, it looks like `git diff -W` should do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Note that GNU diff's `--show-c-function` option doesn't show you the text of the C function the change (hunk) is in, it just shows you the function name in the hunk heading (after the `@@ .. @@` text).

git does the same thing in its diffs by default (at least as of 1.9), and it also makes it configurable via the `core.attributesfile` file.

Comment: how to configure it using core.attributes?

Comment: @TomasM that is explained at e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344577/is-there-a-way-to-ask-git-diff-to-show-the-method-name-instead-of-the-class-name